# Tag merge request: [vxml] and [voicexml]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I believe that [vxml](/questions/tagged/vxml) and [voicexml](/questions/tagged/voicexml) represent the same subject matter, and should be merged.

VXML, I believe, is an abbreviation of Voice XML. It's probably clearer to merge [vxml](/questions/tagged/vxml) into [voicexml](/questions/tagged/voicexml), so that a non expert can pick up on the keyword a little more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag wiki for [vmxl](/questions/tagged/vmxl) contains the following text:

> VoiceXML is designed for creating audio dialogs that feature synthesized speech, digitized audio, recognition of spoken and DTMF key input, recording of spoken input, telephony, and mixed initiative conversations.

[vxml](/questions/tagged/vxml) and [voicexml](/questions/tagged/voicexml) are being used with the same meaning, and there isn't the need to use two tags to mean the same thing.

Comment: Right.  And voicexml is the one that should remain; someone who's just getting started may not know that vxml is the accepted abbreviation.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this shouldn't be done is that many variants of `VXML` are out.  Some companies use the convention of `voiceXML`, but some use `vxml` to differentiate between `ccxml`, `grxml`, etc.

So, both variants of the tag can coexist happily with no issues.

Comment: CCXML and GRXML are not the same as VXML.  VoiceXML and VXML are the same thing, just spelled out, differently.  Though an application can use all three languages, they're still separate languages that have not been sub-classed from each other.

Comment: Wikipedia would like to disagree with you in part. I suggest you not get so heated about responses to your own questions.